# STRB instruction seems not working in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to write string compare function in `ARM assembly`.
After comparing two strings `A` and `B`, one of them should be stored in memory.
If they are not equal, string `B` will be saved in the memory. In below code, storing operation is executed in the label named `StoreA` and `StoreB`(below code is not a complete code)

I expected below code to store a character `H` in `0x00040000` however `STRB` instruction seems not working.
Please give me a advice.

```
AREA Assignment1_2, CODE, READONLY
        ENTRY
Main
    LDR r0,=String1
    LDR r1,=String2

Compare             ; main loop
    LDRB r2, [r0, r5]
    LDRB r3, [r1, r5]

    CMP r2, #0
    BEQ IsEnd1

    CMP r3, #0
    BEQ IsEnd2

    ADD r5, r5, #1
    B Compare


; check if the string ends
IsEnd1
    CMP r3, #0
    BEQ StoreA      ; equal
    B       StoreB      ; not equal

IsEnd2
    CMP r2, #0
    BEQ StoreA      ; equal
    B       StoreB      ; not equal


; store string
StoreA                  ;equal
    SUB r0, r0, r5
    B Endline

StoreB                  ;not equal
    LDRB r3, [r1]
    STRB r3, TEMPADDR
    B Endline

Endline
    MOV pc, lr

TEMPADDR & &00040000
String1 DCB "Hi", 0
String2 DCB "Hik", 0

    END
```

Comment: #1: I don't see any initialization of `r5` being made. #2: What's the memory map of the target device? For all we know, 00040000 might be somewhere in ROM.

Comment: Please be wary when blaming the `STRB` or other instructions. It has been known for there to be processor bugs, but it's unlikely that you have stumbled upon one.

Comment: You are storing a single byte, not a whole string.  Also, this code isn't doing anything close to what you suggest in your comments.  Finally, r5 uninitialized is a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Your main loop `Compare` only checks for string terminators, and does not compare their content. I have only a very little experience in writing code for this processor, so I would only guess what instructions are needed to check the characters within each string.

Also, the two code blocks that are branched to when encountering the `0` end-of-string marker only compare if the strings are the same length.

And "one of them will be stored in memory" is a false belief. Both strings are already stored in memory.